# How to catch exception for Nemiro.OAuth class library in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, dropbox-api

I'm using the Nemiro.OAuth class library for integrating Dropbox API in C#.
Suppose there is an error when I'm making a API call like -

```
 try
                {
                    RequestResult strReq = OAuthUtility.Post
                    (
                        "https://api.dropboxapi.com/1/fileops/move",
                        new HttpParameterCollection
                        {
                            {"access_token", "AccessToken"},  
                            {"root", "auto"},
                            {"from_path", Path.Combine("Path", Name)},
                            {"to_path", (Path.Combine("Path", MovePath) + Name)}
                        }
                    );
               if (strReq.StatusCode == 200)
               {
               }
              else
              {
              }

        }
       catch ()
       {}
```

How do I track the exact error for this request?
If anyone has any idea please share.

Comment: I think calling  public ApiException(RequestResult result, string message) of ApiException class from Nemiro.OAuth class library will do the trick for my requirement. If Anybody has any idea how to call this exception overloaded method from my code catch block please share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RequestException should be used.